# Nuxt does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: javascript, typescript, nuxt.js

I'm trying to run my nuxt project: `npm run dev`, but I keep receiving this error in nuxt:

> The requested module
> '/_nuxt/@fs/Users/jamie/Documents/code/design-system/packages/app/node_modules/.cache/vite/client/deps/@jamie_project_components_src_components_Button_SocialType.js?v=38a7a7a8'
> does not provide an export named 'default'

I really do not understand what's going on here, some kind of typescript issue after an update?

Typescript version is `5.0.2`, and my nuxt version `3.2.3`.

Any ideas?